# Fastest way of numbering instances of a value within a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am looking to number each instance of a value in a vector as it appears. For example the first instance of a value with get '1' the second instance will get '2' and so on - counting how many this value has appeared before it in the vector. I can do this with a for loop in R using the `EuStockMarkets` example data in `datasets`.

```
#load data
data <- as.data.frame(datasets::EuStockMarkets)
df <- data.frame(order = 1:nrow(data),value = data$DAX)
head(df)

#calculate number of instances 
start_time <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
 df[i,"instance"]<- sum(df[1:i,"value"] == df[i,"value"])
}
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
#Time difference of 0.1126978 secs
```

This is fine but I would rather not use a for loop if there was a faster option for much larger datasets and was wondering if their was a preexisting function that - perhaps with tidyverse package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### base R

This is a good use of `ave`:

```r
table(df$instance) # yours
#    1    2    3    4 
# 1774   66   17    3 
df$instance3 <- ave(df$value, df$value, FUN = seq_along)
table(df$instance3)
#    1    2    3    4 
# 1774   66   17    3 
all(df$instance == df$instance3)
# [1] TRUE
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(instance4 = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

---

### Benchmark

No surprise, Waldi's `data.table` breaks out:

```r
DT <- as.data.table(df)
useful.function = function(x) { temp.idx = x[1]; sum(x[2] == df$value[1:temp.idx]); }
bench::mark(
  OP = {
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      df[i,"instance"]<- sum(df[1:i,"value"] == df[i,"value"])
    }
  },
  Waldi = {
    DT[,instance2:=seq_len(.N),by=value]
  },
  r2evans_base = {
    df$instance3 <- ave(df$value, df$value, FUN = seq_along)
  },
  r2evans_dplyr = {
    df %>%
      group_by(value) %>%
      mutate(instance4 = row_number()) %>%
      ungroup()
  },
  PlasticMan = {
    df$instance5 <- apply(df, MARGIN = 1, useful.function)
  },
  min_terations = 500, check = FALSE)
# # A tibble: 5 x 13
#   expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                 time    gc     
#   <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                 <list>  <list> 
# 1 OP             54.42ms  59.45ms      16.6    39.9MB    11.1    300   200     18.07s <NULL> <Rprofmem [7,360 x 3]> <bench~ <tibbl~
# 2 Waldi          997.3us   1.11ms     828.     81.6KB     1.66   499     1   602.36ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [12 x 3]>    <bench~ <tibbl~
# 3 r2evans_base    3.11ms   3.52ms     273.    389.1KB     1.65   497     3      1.82s <NULL> <Rprofmem [35 x 3]>    <bench~ <tibbl~
# 4 r2evans_dplyr  13.04ms  15.85ms      59.5     347KB     6.03   454    46      7.63s <NULL> <Rprofmem [35 x 3]>    <bench~ <tibbl~
# 5 PlasticMan      12.7ms  14.12ms      65.3    26.9MB     4.47   468    32      7.16s <NULL> <Rprofmem [5,507 x 3]> <bench~ <tibbl~
```

Comment: could you recheck the performance comparison, `microbenchmark`  seems to tell that `ave` is much faster than `data.table` : `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(W={df[,instance2:=seq_len(.N),by=value]},
R={df$instance3 <- ave(df$value, df$value, FUN = seq_along)})`

Comment: Updated (with more iterations), not sure what you're seeing. Perhaps `bench::mark` and `microbenchmark` have slightly different internals that are biasing this? idk

Comment: Accepting this answer for doing all the benchmarking. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[,instance2:=seq_len(.N),by=value]

identical(df$instance,df$instance2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks - this is very straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use the `apply()` function:

```
# Loading data.
data = as.data.frame(datasets::EuStockMarkets)
df = data.frame(order = 1:nrow(data), value = data$DAX)
head(df)

# Your solution.
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) 
{
  df[i, "instance"] = sum(df[1:i, "value"] == df[i, "value"])
}

# My solution.
useful.function = function(x)
{
  temp.idx = x[1]
  sum(x[2] == df$value[1:temp.idx])
}

df$instance2 = apply(df, MARGIN = 1, useful.function)

# Double check.
identical(df$instance, df$instance2)

# Benchmarking.
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  your.solution = 
  {
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) 
    {
      sum(df[1:i, "value"] == df[i, "value"])
    }
  },
  my.solution =
  {
    apply(df, MARGIN = 1, useful.function)
  }
)

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr              min       lq     mean    median     uq     max neval
# your.solution() 37.7382 39.92370 44.29684 42.99385 44.67285 98.0862   100
# my.solution()   15.0171 16.52995 21.60575 20.41060 21.32430 75.8235   100
```

Basically, I have written a `useful.function()` that relies on the `df$order` to use only `df$values` up to the position of a certain value to compute what you ask. Then, this function is *applied* to each row of `df` with `apply()`. The results of `microbenchmarking` (which evaluates both solutions 100 times so to see which one is faster) shows that using `apply()` is about twice as faster than the `for` loop. This derives from the fact that the loop needs to make a lot of call (`nrow(df)` in your case) to other functions (possibly written in C), while `apply()` makes a single call.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense and is very adaptable.